# Calculate Date with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, system-administration

I am trying to create a script in Powershell that will;

Get Last Bootup Time of the PC and check if it's greater than 48hrs
If it's greater Reboot machine
Else exit

I can't seem to get it to calculate correctly.

```
cls
# Declaring Variables

$lbt = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select LastBootUpTime
$lbt = $lbt.lastbootuptime
$ts = "{0:t}" -f $lbt
$texp = $lbt.AddHours(0)
#$ts = New-TimeSpan -Hours +3  #48 Hours Time Span from the last Boot Up Time

# Get Last Boot Up Time and compare
# Check LastBootUpTime
# If LastBootUpTime is grater than 48hrs continue executing ELSE RemoveIfExist -eq $true


Write-host "Last Boot      : " $lbt
write-host "Now            : " (Get-Date) `n


If ($lbt -ge $texp) {
Write-Host "Last Boot have been MORE than" ("{0:t}" -f $texp) hrs `n`n`n
}
else {
write-host "Last Boot have been LESS then" ("{0:t}" -f $texp) hrs `n`n`n
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use this function :

```
function LastBootUpMoreThan ($hour){
  $dt = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select LastBootUpTime
  if (($dt.LastBootUpTime).AddHours($hour) -gt (get-date)) {$false}else {$true}
}
```

You can test :

```
 if ((LastBootUpMoreThan 48)){"Reboot"}else{"Don't reboot"}
```

Comment: `if (($dt.LastBootUpTime).AddHours($hour)`

should be...

`if (($lbt.LastBootUpTime).AddHours($hour)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this can work:

```
$lbt = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select LastBootUpTime
$now = get-date

if ( [math]::abs(($lbt.lastbootuptime - $now).totalhours) -gt 48 ) 
{
   "Last Boot have been MORE than 48 hrs ago"
}
else 
{
   "Last Boot have been LESS then 48 hrs ago"
}
```

Comment: The [math]::Abs() isn't really needed unless you expect the last booted time to be sometime in the future. Just reverse the subtraction.

Comment: @EBGreen and who knows if someone has moved the time forward? :-P

Comment: You don't, but if they have then Get-Date would be moved forward too. Also, if they are monkeying with the time, calculating the time since last reboot is meaningless anyway.

Comment: @EBGreen 
you're too serious ... keep calm and relax ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`SWbemDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to convert a WMI time string to a `DateTime` object that you can compare to `Get-Date` values:

```psh
$hours = 48

$lbt = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem |
       select -Expand LastBootUpTime

$convert = New-Object -COM 'WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime'
$convert.Value = $lbt

if ($convert.GetVarDate() -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-$hours)) {
  Write-Host "Last Boot have been MORE than $hours hours."
} else {
  Write-Host "Last Boot have been LESS than $hours hours."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner using `ticks` to compare

```
 if (((Get-Date).Ticks) -gt ((Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select LastBootUpTime).LastBootUpTime.Ticks+(New-TimeSpan -Hours +48).ticks)) { "Reboot" }
```